# Portable Class Library + XDocument.Load(uri)?

Tags: c#, xml, portable-class-library

When I create a normal application or class library I can use `XDocument.Load(some xml file on the internet)` to download and then parse the XML within that file.

However, I'm writing code for a PCL and it seems XDocument does not have the option of a string URI. The only options are `System.IO.Stream`, `System.IO.TextReader`, and `System.Xml.XmlReader`.

How should I proceed to be able to access an XML file on the internet? Should I make use of the new-ish `HttpClient` and use a stream from that somehow?

Comment: Yes, make the http call yourself and feed `XDocument` with the stream you get back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code:

```
HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://your_site.com/etc");
using (WebResponse response = http.GetResponse())
{
      Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
      XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
      // Use the xDoc...
}
```

Comment: Add quite a bit of `using` statements and this code should be fine.

Comment: I believe that only `response` need to be closed/disposed, so I will add that. Thanks.